# Setting up backup strategy for backing up postgresql database on cloud foundry

Tags: postgresql, backup, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

We have setup a community postgresql service on Cloud Foundry (IBM Blumix). This is a free service and no automated backup and recovery is supported out of the box.

Is there a way to set up a standby server or a regular backup in case there is any data corruption/failure?

IBM compose and ElephantSQL can provide this service at a cost, butwe are not ready for it yet.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL is an experimental service and there is not a dashboard and other advanced features (Daily backup for example) that you can find in other services that you mentioned. If you want to do a backup you could write an ad-hoc script that 'saves'\exports all tables as you want and run it every day.
If you need PostegreSQL you can create a **PostegreSQL** by compose service $17.50 / mo for the first GB and $12 for Extra GB )

Answer (score 0):

We used [Postgresql Studio](http://www.postgresqlstudio.org/) and deployed it on IBM Bluemix. The database service was connected to the pgstudio interface (This restricts the access to only connected databases). We also had to make minor changes to pgstudio so that we could use pg_dump with the interface.

The result: We could manually dump the data. This solution works well as we could take regular dumps (though manually).

Answer (score 0):

In the free tier you are right in saying that you cant get the backup. Those features are available only in Compose for PostgresSQL service - but that's a paid service.